# React-native android ignores navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Tags: android, geolocation, react-native

I'm trying to use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` on my Android device (Philips Xenium). It works absolutely ok in iphone and genimotion simulator.
`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` returns absolutely nothing - no errors, no success. 
However, if I turn off geolocation service in my smartphone, it returns `No available location provider`.

Also, `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` works fine.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I got the exact same issue..

Comment: Same here. And I can't show the current location on a map, which I imagine is the same issue

Comment: I have had the same strange issue. It worked for me when I put the device's position-settings to high-accuracy or battery-saving (wifi + cellular), but not when the setting was device only (GPS).

Comment: Did anyone find a resolution to this issue? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Are you testing inside a building? If yes can you just try to test it outside where you have a better reception and see if it works?

Comment: I'm having the same issue only with certain phones... works with Samsung S7 for ex. (tested on android 6 + 7) but doesn't work on samsung S5 with android 5.0

Answer (score 3):

Add the following permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

and then pass an enableHighAccuracy object to your your geolocation.getCurrentPosition method:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that **Location** is enabled in your device.

I enabled `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`, however I kept having the same error until I realized that location was disabled.